# IntelliJ "1001 Undefined" popup on hover

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I hover over a `this.` method or variable IntelliJ will display the standard popup documentation, but a few moments later there's another popup with just an "Undefined" message.

I'm not sure what's causing it, but I want to stop it from happening.

It seems to only occur when in debugger mode.

[image]

This is in TypeScript, if that helps.

I've tried disabling suspect plugins, searching settings, google, ChatGPT. No good.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

- "Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views"
- Deselect `Show value tooltip. Value tooltip delay (ms):`

[image: Solution]